# Angular 6 with Saas Module not found: Error

Tags: module, angular5

I am new to angular and trying to setup it locally. I am facing an error and trying to fix from last 1 day.

Here is the error i am getting:

```
ERROR in multi ./scss/styles.scss ../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./scss/font-awesome.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\angular\my-app\scss\font-awesome.scss' in 'D:\miet\miet-app'
ERROR in multi ./scss/styles.scss ../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./scss/font-awesome.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\angular\my-app\scss\styles.scss' in 'D:\miet\miet-app'
ERROR in multi ./scss/styles.scss ../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./scss/font-awesome.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\angular\node_modules\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.css' in 'D:\angular\my-app
```

My folder structure is `D:\miet\miet-app` and inside this folder i have `node_modules` and `src` folders

Here is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "miet-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/miet-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "scss/styles.scss",
              "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss",
                "scss"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "miet-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "miet-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "miet-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "miet-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "miet-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "miet-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "miet-app"
}
```

I have placed my font-awesome files inside `src/scss/font-awesome` and in `node_module/font-awesome`

Here is my app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone help me where i am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm --depth 9999 update
npm rebuild node-sass
```

If doesn't work remove `node_modules` folder and repeat commands above.